# Share Extension is not working in Chrome

Tags: ios, ios8-share-extension

I am working on Share Extension

Here is code of info.plist file . this is working fine in Safari, But not in Chrome.

```
 <key>NSExtension</key>
        <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsImageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>0</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
        </dict> 


        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
```

Any idea? how to enable share extension in Chrome as well

Comment: Just to add some value, two references about this.

http://www.pixeldock.com/blog/how-to-show-your-ios-share-extension-only-in-safari-or-other-browsers/
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/SystemExtensionKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014212-SW10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are missing some code . For chrome you need to pass js file as well

```
<dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebPageWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
                <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                <integer>1</integer>
            </dict>
            <key>NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile</key>
            <string>DemoPreprocessor</string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
        <string>MainInterface</string>
        <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
        <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
```

for  more detials Please visit demo extension code from this [link](https://github.com/hitubansal123/iOS-Extension-Demo/blob/master/Share%20to%20Note/Info.plist)

Comment: this is not working for me..Please help to me to solve

Comment: what issue you are facing. please explain

Comment: I tested the Chrome browser, it did not execute the Javascript Preprocessor, while the Safari browser did.

Comment: Works only in safari.

Comment: its not working for me even safari browser not working but i am getting URL.please suggest me what i am  doing wrong.

Comment: This answer is definitely not correct — Chrome will not execute the NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile, only Safari

Answer (score 1):

in my case, only adding the JS file with "**NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile**" did not solve the problem.

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
            <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
            <dict>
                    <key>NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingFile</key>
                    <string>Action</string>
                    <key>NSExtensionActivationRule</key>
                    <dict>
                            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
                            <true/>
                            <key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsWebURLWithMaxCount</key>
                            <integer>1</integer>
                    </dict>
            </dict>
            <key>NSExtensionMainStoryboard</key>
            <string>MainInterface</string>
            <key>NSExtensionPointIdentifier</key>
            <string>com.apple.share-services</string>
    </dict>
```

It's also essential to add the :

```
<key>NSExtensionActivationSupportsText</key>
<true/>
```

I currently don't know why.

I've found this in the official documentation :  **NSExtensionActivationSupportsText** : Include this key to indicate to the system and to other apps that your app supports text.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

only safari use this array 
NSItemProvider = [[NSExtensionItem attachments] firstObject];
other browser use the API 
NSItemProvider = [[NSExtensionItem attachments] objectAtIndex:1];

Answer (score -1):

No need to edit plist. This works both in Google Chrome and Safari:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    for item in extensionContext!.inputItems {
        if let attachments = item.attachments {
            for itemProvider in attachments! {
                itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier("public.url", options: nil, completionHandler: { (object, error) -> Void in
                    if object != nil {
                        println(object) //This is your URL
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Don't understand why this answer got 2 downvotes. +1 and thank you.