# iOS Share Extension unable to get shared URL from Chrome

Tags: ios, iphone, ios8-share-extension

I am trying to implement share extension for my app. Its working good in safari browser and youtube app (i.e) when i share from these apps i get the public.url which is the url to be shared.

When i tried the same in chrome it was not showing the extension. When i added the NSExtensionActivationSupportsText under the NSExtensionActivationRule to true its started showing. But when i try to share the contents i am unable to fetch the URL String which is to be shared. I get only contentText.

I have followed the approach shown in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/31942744/6199038.

I have also added the demoProcessor.js

```
var MyPreprocessor = function() {};
MyPreprocessor.prototype = {
run: function(arguments) {
    arguments.completionFunction({"URL": document.URL, "pageSource": document.documentElement.outerHTML, "title": document.title, "selection": window.getSelection().toString()});
}
};
var ExtensionPreprocessingJS = new MyPreprocessor;
```

I am using **SLComposeServiceViewController**

In my ShareViewController.m i am trying to get the data as shown below,

for safari i used this which is working fine

```
NSExtensionItem *item = self.extensionContext.inputItems.firstObject;
NSItemProvider *itemProvider = [[item.userInfo valueForKey:NSExtensionItemAttachmentsKey] objectAtIndex:0];
if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:@"public.url"]) {
    [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"public.url" options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
        urlString = url.absoluteString;
        NSLog(@"urlString %@",urlString);
    }];
}
```

Then i modified my code to this to get the URL from chrome, Which is not working.

```
 for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems) {
    for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments) {
        if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePropertyList]) {
            [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypePropertyList options:nil completionHandler:^(NSDictionary *jsDict, NSError *error) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSDictionary *jsPreprocessingResults = jsDict[NSExtensionJavaScriptPreprocessingResultsKey];

                    NSString *selectedText = jsPreprocessingResults[@"selection"];
                    NSString *pageTitle = jsPreprocessingResults[@"title"];
                    NSString *URL = jsPreprocessingResults[@"URL"];

                    NSLog(@"selectedText %@",selectedText);
                    NSLog(@"pageTitle %@",pageTitle);
                    NSLog(@"URL %@",URL);
                });
            }];

            break;
        }
    }

}
```

**PLEASE ADVICE**

Answer (score 2):

I have solved it myself. As it was not entering inside the "loadItemForTypeIdentifier" method. So i had modified my method to the below code

```
for (NSExtensionItem *item in self.extensionContext.inputItems) {
        for (NSItemProvider *itemProvider in item.attachments) {

            NSString *URLinPlainText = [item.attributedContentText string];
            if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL]) {
                [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL options:nil completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {

                    urlString = url.absoluteString;
                    NSLog(@"<< URL >> %@",urlString);
                    return;
                }];
            }
            else if (URLinPlainText)  {
                // In Some app i got the URL in a Plain text mode
                if([URLinPlainText containsString:@"http"]){
                    urlString = [sharedPlainText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
                    NSLog(@"<< URL >> %@",urlString);
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

And also i have removed the demoProcessor.js.
Now i am able to get the URL from almost all the News Apps, Browsers like (Chrome, firefox, safari) and in some of the apps i am getting the shared url in the form of plain text which is then i had to remove the empty spaces and convert it to NSString.

According to my understanding the demoprocessor.js is used if user wants to access the url page properties for ex(title, baseURL, og:image, og:description etc...) which works only for safari browser.

Comment: Safer to use `if ([URLinPlainText hasPrefix:@"http://"]){` as your current test would be valid for the URL `ftp://httpsomethingelse.com`